# Can any one explain me Dblink query format

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.3, dblink

I need to retrieve data from tables which is located in two different database 
so need to use dblink , but not able to understand its format 
dblink(???) as(??)

Comment: I don't understand the question. You simply pass a SQL statement to the function.

Comment: example : SELECT towns.*
FROM dblink('dbname=somedb','SELECT town, pop1980 FROM towns')
    AS towns(town varchar(21), pop1980 integer); explain me meaning of each paramter

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you're on one database and you want to query another?

First of all you'll need to make sure that **postgresql-contrib** is installed

in my case

```
dnf install postgresql-contrib-9.4.6-1.fc23.x86_64
```

Then you need to create the extension in postgresql to use dblink.

```
 create extension dblink;
```

Here's is a simple example

```
SELECT * FROM dblink('dbname=Test','SELECT date1, int2 FROM test1') AS test(date1 date, int2 integer);
```

I've tested this and it works fine.

All the best

Ref [Postgresql dblink](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dblink.html)